# Listview jump to top when adding new item

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-asynctask

i am making application that have scroll listener that add data from multiple URL
but when i scroll  the list jump to first position and than load the URL i know that the adapter in my a sync task get executed every time i load new URL task when i load new item but i don't  know how to fix it

```
public class jsontask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<newsmodel>> {


    @Override
    protected List<newsmodel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (connectiondetector.isConnected()) {
                connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            } else {
                moviemodelList.addAll((List<newsmodel>) cacheThis.readObject(
                       technology.this, fileName));

            }
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);

            }


            String finaljson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentobject = new JSONObject(finaljson);


            JSONArray parentarray = parentobject.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < parentarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = parentarray.getJSONObject(i);
                newsmodel newsmodel = new newsmodel();
                newsmodel.setAuthor(finalobject.getString("author"));
                if (finalobject.isNull("author")) {

                }
                newsmodel.setDescription(finalobject.getString("description"));
                newsmodel.setTitle(finalobject.getString("title"));
                newsmodel.setImage(finalobject.getString("urlToImage"));
                newsmodel.setUrl(finalobject.getString("url"));

                newsmodel.setPublishedAt(finalobject.getString("publishedAt"));
                cacheThis.writeObject(technology.this, fileName, moviemodelList);
                moviemodelList.add(newsmodel);

            }


            return moviemodelList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return moviemodelList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return moviemodelList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {


            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.read();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        return moviemodelList;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<newsmodel> result) {


        super.onPostExecute(result);
        newsadapter adapter = new newsadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        lvnews.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


public class newsadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<newsmodel> moviemodelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public newsadapter(Context context, int resource, List<newsmodel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        moviemodelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }`
```

and this is how i excute my a sync task

```
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    moviemodelList.clear();
    new jsontask().execute("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=engadget&sortBy=top&apiKey=ade8f00a634b4825a028837ec107afae");
    lvnews.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

            new jsontask().execute("url1");
            new jsontask().execute("url2");
            new jsontask().execute("url3");
            new jsontask().execute("url4");
            new jsontask().execute("url5");
            new jsontask().execute("url6");
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from onPostExecute

```
newsadapter adapter = new newsadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
lvnews.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You are setting adapter eveytime after executing doInBackground. You need to do it only once. You can do it in onCreate

> *The basic methods used in an android AsyncTask class are defined below*
>   :
>
> **doInBackground() :** This method contains the code which needs to be executed in background. In this method we can send results multiple
>   times to the UI thread by publishProgress() method. To notify that the
>   background processing has been completed we just need to use the
>   return statements
>
> **onPreExecute() :** This method contains the code which is executed before the background processing starts
>
> **onPostExecute() :** This method is called after doInBackground method completes processing. Result from doInBackground is passed to
>   this method
>
> **onProgressUpdate() :** This method receives progress updates from  doInBackground method, which is published via publishProgress method,
>   and this method can use this progress update to update the UI thread

Please refer this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial) to know how Async task

Comment: thank you it worked but i have to go to another activity and than go back to main activity to make it show the news how can i fix this

Comment: add adapter.notifyItemChanged(moviemodelList.size()); after moviemodelList.add(newsmodel); in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

After getting first url response call for second **new jsontask().execute("url2");** then call for third, fourth and so on.

Make a common code to reuse it again and again.

try this link : http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/android-listview-dynamically-load-more.html